# Delete Data from a pandas array that is out of range

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas array like this:

```
       x        y               z
  35.013930 048.775597        0.22 
  42.015619 368.803652        0.00 
  03.017302 349.831709        1.20
  05.018978 378.859767        2.20 
  07.020646 300.887827        0.05
  23.022307 044.915887        0.23
      .           .             . 
      .           .             . 
      .           .             .
```

with around 40.000 rows.

I need to delete the rows whose data `(x, y)` are not in the range `y:(44,350.5)` and `x:(4.5,35.8)`.

So, the output would be something like this:

```
      x        y               z
  35.013930 048.775597        0.22  
  07.020646 300.887827        0.05
  23.022307 044.915887        0.23                    
      .           .             .
      .           .             .
```

I think that using `np.where(np.logical_and())` with the columns `x, y`, might be a solution, but I don't know how to do it.  Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: How are you storing your "matrix"? Is it numpy, pandas, lists, etc?

Comment: Yes, I know how. Please share with us your attempts.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your range is supposed to work (it's not clear to me from your example), but have a look at filter(lambda, list)

Comment: It's a pandas array, and I want to delete all rows whose x are not in (4.5, 44) and y (35.8, 350.5),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). I try use `conditions`, which get recommended output and then `conditions` by text of question:

```
print df

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#1  42.015619  368.803652  0.00
#2   3.017302  349.831709  1.20
#3   5.018978  378.859767  2.20
#4   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#5  23.022307   44.915887  0.23
```

```
print df.loc[(df.y > 44) & (df.y < 350.5) & (df.x > 4.5) & (df.x < 35.8)]

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#4   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#5  23.022307   44.915887  0.23

print df.query('y > 44 and y < 350.5 and x > 4.5 and x < 35.8')

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#4   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#5  23.022307   44.915887  0.23
```

```
print df.loc[~((df.y > 44) & (df.y < 350.5) & (df.x > 4.5) & (df.x < 35.8))]

#           x           y    z
#1  42.015619  368.803652  0.0
#2   3.017302  349.831709  1.2
#3   5.018978  378.859767  2.2

print df.query(' not (y > 44 and y < 350.5 and x > 4.5 and x < 35.8)')

#           x           y    z
#1  42.015619  368.803652  0.0
#2   3.017302  349.831709  1.2
#3   5.018978  378.859767  2.2
```

Or with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#1  42.015619  368.803652  0.00
#2   3.017302  349.831709  1.20
#3   5.018978  378.859767  2.20
#4   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#5  23.022307   44.915887  0.23
```

```
print df.loc[(df.y > 44) & (df.y < 350.5) & (df.x > 4.5) & (df.x < 35.8)]
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#1   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#2  23.022307   44.915887  0.23

print df.query('y > 44 and y < 350.5 and x > 4.5 and x < 35.8')
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#           x           y     z
#0  35.013930   48.775597  0.22
#1   7.020646  300.887827  0.05
#2  23.022307   44.915887  0.23
```

```
print df.loc[~((df.y > 44) & (df.y < 350.5) & (df.x > 4.5) & (df.x < 35.8))]
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#           x           y    z
#0  42.015619  368.803652  0.0
#1   3.017302  349.831709  1.2
#2   5.018978  378.859767  2.2


print df.query(' not (y > 44 and y < 350.5 and x > 4.5 and x < 35.8)')
        .reset_index(drop=True)

#           x           y    z
#0  42.015619  368.803652  0.0
#1   3.017302  349.831709  1.2
#2   5.018978  378.859767  2.2
```